# JavaScript Bar Graph (Not a traditional bar graph)

Tags: javascript, html, bar-chart

In JavaScript I am trying to print out little ticks/hashes/lines (see image attached) to my html. I've tried googling a lot of things but haven't come across any bar graphs like this and I was wondering if anyone new how to do this, or could link me to some resources that would point me in the right direction.
[Example of what i am Trying to achieve](http://kylebinger.com/javascript/bar_graph.jpg)
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try filling an element with pipe characters like this: `10 | |||||| (6)`.

Comment: Just draw lots of `|` characters? If the regular `|` is too wide, check other fonts; there are also bound to be more characters that look like it (a Sans serif lowercase L for example).

Comment: Thanks so much guys! These answers helped as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a traditional bar graph... if you think laterally.

You can create a traditional bar graph in HTML by drawing a `<div>` element of the correct width, with a border and a fill colour.

You can turn it into a bar like the one you want to achieve by removing the border and replacing the solid fill colour with a simple background image that contains the line pattern.